# XSLT to remove particular attribute from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

i am new to XSLT need help in removing an attribute from XML. Nothing to be changed in the output from XSLT, except removing the attribute

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 
pain.001.001.03.xsd"
```

from the 'Document'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 
pain.001.001.03.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the namespace from the root element, try the below code to remove the namespace attributes

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Input XML:     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 pain.001.001.03.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
 <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
 Desired output :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
 <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>

Answer (score 0):

You have to include in your script an **empty template** for the attribute to
omit:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[name() = 'xsi:schemaLocation']"/>
```

To copy the source without any other changes, you need also the
*identity template*.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/bEJaofE

### Edit

The above template will actually remove **every** *xsi:schemaLocation* attribute,
regardless of its position in the document.
If you want to remove this attribute **only from the root node**,
change the template to:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/@*[name() = 'xsi:schemaLocation']"/>
```

Note added `/*/` to match only attributes of the root node, whatever its name.

Comment: Hi Valdi, thanks for you reply. I have tried your code, it is working to remove the attribute, checked in FreeFormatter. Strangely when i insert the same code in SAP PI(7.1) the transformation is not happening. I am not really sure what's going through,any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I know nothing about SAP. Maybe for some reason it requires this attribute? Maybe you should post another question, but marking it with relevant tag concerning SAP?

Answer (score 0):

Is better to use `xsl:copy-of />` , try below

```
<xsl:template match="Document/node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`
```